# What did Sisyphus know and when did he know it?

Tags: greek

Each time that Sisyphus began to roll the boulder up the mountain was he aware *before* beginning the task that the boulder would roll back down once he had finished? In other words, in addition to being compelled to undertake a task that he could never complete, was he also given the additional burden of knowing he was engaged in a futile task? Will you please refer me to any resources you have used to support your conclusion?

Although I can imagine the gods having the power implant a desire in a man, I find it more difficult to believe (based on my limited education on the topic) that they can force a man to do something against his will. So, if the gods can force a man to do something against his will, can you provide other examples of where they have been so?

Comment: This is a good question, but the last paragraph seems to lead it into the territory of being Too Broad.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the following passage from The Encyclopedia of Mythology by Arthur Cotterrell (and other common versions of the myth), I don't believe that Sisyphus knew in advance the futility of his efforts:

> "Finally, Zeus lost patience and condemned Sisyphus to Tartarus to pay for his lifelong impiety. For the rest of eternity he had to roll a block of stone to the top of a hill only to see it roll back again as it reached the crest."

I believe that the entire point of the punishment was to trick him to believe that he was going to succeed. This is purely speculative, since no version of the myth I read answers this question explicitly. Moreover, I don't think that he had any choice in the matter, it wasn't *his* desire to roll the boulder. It resembles Hell in Christianity, those who suffer don't have their say in the matter.

Comment: yay sources! +1 and welcome to the site!